# C# Regex escape and replace

Tags: c#, json, regex, replace

I have an API that sends out documents to email. I'm using a paramater that allows me to specify the email message. It requires line breaks to be in Json format (\n). I'm using Regex to escape the textbox text like shown below.

```
string JsonMessage = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(this.txtMailMessage.Text), System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(this.txtMailMessage.Text));
        JsonMessage = JsonMessage.Replace("\r", "");
        Console.WriteLine(JsonMessage);
```

Here is a example output: 5\r\n5\r\n5

As shown I'm trying to replace the \r in order to achieve the "line break" in Json. So it would look like this: 5\n5\n5

What I can't seem to wrap me head around is that when I cast the `JsonMessage = JsonMessage.Replace("\r", "");` it does not replace the \r

Comment: Try `JsonMessage.Replace("\\r", "");`

Comment: Output the JsonMessage string **before** the attempted replacement to the Console. Note that if you see literally \r in the output - i mean literally a backslash followed by an r -, then you don't have any "\r" in your JsonMessage. `"\r"` is a string with only ONE character; that character being CR (carriage return). This character is not visible, so seeing \r in the console ouput would be evidence that there is not `"\r"` in your JsonMessage , but rather `"\\r"`.

Comment: @G5W Thanks that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JsonMessage.Replace("\\r", "");`
The `\\` will be interpreted as a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing "\r" with nothing try and replace "\r\n" with "\n" as

```
        string mystring = "5\r\n5\r\n5";
        mystring = mystring.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

This will produce "5\n5\n5"